# Receiver has no segue with identifier in self.performSegue(withIdentifier, sender)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10

I'm getting this follow message when I try open a table item in my 'add' form to update it.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'verBeneficioSegue''

Github with project: https://github.com/felipeejunges/MyBenefits

Segue:
[image]

My code:
[image]

When I was debbuging I got error in line 58.

P.S. I'm doing a project exercise for my post-degree in iOS.
I try to clean up project, restart Xcode, restart my Mac, but nothing worked.

Comment: The code shown is inside `MyBenefits` class ?

Comment: The error message seems pretty straightforward. What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the crash the segue is inside vc named `ListarBeneficiosTableViewController`

> ListarBeneficiosTableViewController: 0x7fbf6d510340>) has
>   no segue with identifier 'verBeneficioSegue'

and your vc shown in picture is named `MyBeneficio` ( it's a `UITaBarController` ) which isn't the same hence the crash

If your purpose is to add another tab to the tabs controller you should drag the segue from the tab to the listoVC and select `viewControllers` from the popup

Otherwise the segue origin should be `ListarBeneficiosTableViewController` and it's destination is another vc

Comment: you can't set a tableControllers class to a tab controller in IB , does the listvc is a tab you need to add ?? or you need to navigate to it when some action happens in the tab ?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "verBeneficio", sender: beneficio)
```

in your ListarBeneficiosTableViewController class. This implies that your ListarBeneficiosTableViewController instance is loaded from the storyboard and in the storyboard it has a segue called "verBeneficio".

Okay, so let's look in the storyboard. When we do, we see that the "verBeneficio" segue does not come from the ListarBeneficiosTableViewController. It comes from the tab view controller.

Comment: So, how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "fix it". I don't know what you are trying to do. If you wanted `"verBeneficio"` to come from ListarBeneficiosTableViewController, you should have drawn it in the storyboard coming from ListarBeneficiosTableViewController. If you want `"verBeneficio"` to come from the tab bar controller then you want to refer to the tab bar controller, not `self`, to perform the segue.